# jquery full calendar is not getting loaded in Chrome 10 browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, wicket, fullcalendar

I have used a jquery control full calendar from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/. I have used that control in a wicket application, where in one page there are two tabs, and in one tab there  are some text-fields and in the other this calendar control.

But now for my local server everything is fine. But when I deploy my application on development server then, in Chrome and Safari calendar comes for the first time when i go to the calendar tab. But when I navigate to the other tab and come back again then calendar never comes again. This works fine for FF and IE.

Because I have not seen this issue locally thats why don't have any clue. Seeking help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you importing the scripts into the pages? Post some code, or we won't be able to help you much

Answer (score 0):

Wicket probably does not know about the calendar control. Can you call the Javascript function to enable the calendar again after you switch back to the calendar tab? That will probably solve the issue.

The best way to integrate JQuery and Wicket is probably [WiQuery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/), which prevents this kind of problems. The general issue here is that Wicket manages state, but the client side also has some state. This state needs to be synced or managed somehow. WiQuery solved that 'state' problem.